# Trying to calculate the probability of a game's item drop system involving multiple independent duplicate-excluding checks

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have a game that assigns the probability of finding items in treasure chests by making several independent checks until it fills a quota, with duplicates not allowed. I am trying to figure out how to calculate the resulting probabilities of finding each item - without breaking the bank in terms of calculation brute force.

For an example: The % chance of getting a small chest is 30. For a medium chest it's 15, and for a big chest it's 5. (There is no requirement that these add to 100.)

The algorithm:

- Roll random against the large's 5%.
- If successful, it's a large. If not, roll random against the medium's 15%.
- If successful, it's a medium. If not, roll random against the small's 30%.
- If successful, it's a small. If not, return to rolling for the large, and repeat the process indefinitely until *something* is successful.

This is then repeated over three layers. The layers are:

- size of treasure chest
- item category (e.g. weapon or armour)
- specific item (e.g. for weapons: sword or pike; for armour: helmet, gloves, or boots)

So first the game makes this "roll until success" check to decide what chest to get. The chest selected determines which item pool is drawn from and how many items are needed. For each item needed, the game does a "roll until success" check for category, and then another for item. It repeats these two checks until it has the requisite number of items. Duplicates are not allowed; if an item would be a duplicate, the process is restarted. (Which I think is identical to changing the % chance of potential duplicates to 0.)

I am trying to, given the % chances for everything in all 3 layers, calculate the final probability that you will get a chest that has a specific item in it. I'm not looking for a one-time result of any particular example data: I'd like help in figuring out how to formulate the algorithm so I can apply it to any data.

This is giving me a headache for two reasons:

- It's really close to being a geometric distribution, but because the "success rate" at each step is not identical, it isn't. Also you have to fudge the meaning of "success" because what item you get matters.
- Ignoring duplicates is a pain. If item 2 is in a different category than item 1, there's no effect. But if item 2 is in the same category - or if one category has been completely exhausted - the rest of the things in that level all have different rates for item 2.

The brute force way of formulating this doesn't seem too hard (e.g. doing the $(1-p)^k(p)$ thing for each p in order a bunch of times). But I don't want to use brute force, because I have to present the data [using MediaWiki](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Calculation), which *can* do this given the variable and loop extensions but I imagine doing this a ton will not be ideal - taking 2 items from a chest that has 4 categories and 3 things in each category looks like I need 21 iterations of $(1-p)^k(p)$ (1 for "chance of picking this", 1 for each other option to get "chance of picking this given I previously picked that"). If possible, I'm looking for something more pragmatic.

---

Other notes:

- Some items can appear in more than one size of chest, with different rates. It should be easy enough to calculate them separately and proportionally add them together.

Related-looking questions:

- [Exhibit A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805529/algorithm-game-item-drop-probability) - Very similar, but no answer.
- [Exhibit B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341703/what-is-the-probability-of-an-item-in-a-list-being-chosen-if-both-the-list-and-i) - The same problem in essence (including the part where there's multiple levels of selection), but without the all-important "repeat until something succeeds" condition.

---

Examples of possible data:

```
Set 1
 1% large chest (pick 2)
  50% weapon
   30% big sword
   10% claymore
  20% armour
   50% steel helmet
   50% steel gauntlets
   50% steel boots
  10% jewel
   20% ruby
   30% sapphire
   40% emerald
  20% potion
   10% red potion
   20% blue potion
   30% green potion
   40% yellow potion
 10% medium chest (pick 2)
  50% potion
   40% water
   20% red potion
  10% weapon
   40% medium sword
  20% armour
   40% iron helmet
   40% iron boots
 100% small chest (10% chance of pick 2, 90% chance of pick 1)
  100% creature bits
   15% tail
   70% hair
Set 2
 5% large chest (pick 2)
  50% weapon
   30% claymore
   30% big sword
   20% giant club
  30% armour
   100% magic bracelet
  10% jewel
   50% emerald
   100% diamond
  30% potion
   10% red potion
   20% blue potion
   30% green potion
   40% yellow potion
 15% medium chest (pick 2)
  40% potion
   80% water
   10% red potion
  5% weapon
   40% small sword
   20% medium sword
  25% armour
   40% iron helmet
   40% iron boots
 100% small chest (10% chance of pick 2, 90% chance of pick 1)
  100% creature bits
   40% tail
   70% hair
```

Comment: Most of this is not a question, it is a complaint that you do not know how to simplify the calculation.  You do not present enough information for someone to help you.  I showed how to calculate the probability of each kind of chest.  Please study it, see if it helps for the other parts, and edit the question to include enough data to do the calculation.

Comment: If you are withholding help until I add example data for every step, you are missing the point. (Which perhaps I did not make clear enough, and will edit in.) I am not asking for help in doing the calculation once for a specific example; I am asking if there is a way to represent the algorithm in a simpler form than hundreds of chained multiplications, so I don't need to burn as much CPU in generating the values for thousands of cases.

Comment: Alright perhaps it may still be useful for me to add a few different examples. I'll do that.

Comment: (apparently I originally listed the chests backwards, they're calculated in the order large-medium-small, not small-medium-large...my bad, fixed)

Comment: It just is complicated.  I don't know how to give general advice, which it seems you are seeking, because it depends on the details of how things are chosen and which interact with which.  Another approach is just to compute thousands, even millions, of drops as a simulation.  It won't take long.

Comment: I am disappointed but not entirely surprised, very well.

Answer (score 1):

Note:  this was done when the chests were checked small, medium, large.  The same approach works in the opposite order, but the numbers change a bit.

Given your chest algorithm, the chances of the three kinds of chest must add to $100\%$ because you *will* generate a chest-you keep trying until you do.  We can calculate the chance of each kind.  The chance we generate a chest on the first round is $1-.7\cdot .85 \cdot .95=\frac{1739}{4000}$  The chance we generate a small chest is then $0.3 \cdot \frac {4000}{1739}\approx 0.69$  The chance we generate a medium chest is $0.7 \cdot 0.15 \cdot \frac {4000}{1739}\approx 0.24$ and the chance for a large chest is $0.7 \cdot 0.85 \cdot 0.05 \cdot \frac {4000}{1739} \approx 0.07$.

You can do a similar calculation for the other parts but did not present the information to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could rephrase this by instead of using the repeated rolls you just give the disjoint probabilities for one go through the three sizes. So you state you have $5\%$ for large, if unsucessfull, $15\%$ for a medium chest, if unsucessfull, $30\%$ for a small chest.

This is exactly the same as having a single roll with a $5\%$ chance for a large chest, a $0.95*15\%=14.25\%$ chance for a medium chest and a $(1-0.05-0.1425)*0.3=24.225\%$ chance for a small chest. So you could simplify by instead of rolling 3 times you just roll once with these adjusted probabilites.

Next you stated that if no chest is rolled you start with the $5\%$ for large and go through the process again. You can simplify a second time by noting that you will get a chest eventually and the relative probabilities didn't change. So the chance to end up with a large is $5\%/(5\%+14.25\%+24.225\%) \approx 11.5\%$, for a medium is $14.25\%/(5\%+14.25\%+24.225\%) \approx 32.8\%$ and for a small is $24.225\%/(5\%+14.25\%+24.225\%) \approx 55.7\%$. So instead of going through the repeated sequence of rolls you can just rolls once and use these computed probabilities.

You have to do the computation once but then you can implement it and describe it much faster by just using the calculated probabilities.